# How to subtract every element in a column from its counterpart in another column?

Tags: matlab

I realise that I can do this via a loop, but was wondering if there was some simpler way to do it.

Comment: I think that it is about time that we start closing these kind of questions as too localized. The next thing we know is people will ask us "how to add 2 matrixes", and there will be an answer "use +".

Comment: @Andrey: It's definitely not too localized. But I agree with the general idea, maybe it's "not a real question"?

Comment: @Junuxx, yes "too localized" is not exactly a good definition. Maybe "not a real question" is better. The important thing is that we close them down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subtract them?

```
>>  foo = round(20*rand(6,2))  # generate a random matrix with 2 columns

foo =                    

    13     9
     6    18
     0    11
    13    14
    17     4
    10     3

>>  foo(:,1) - foo(:,2)         # first column minus second column

ans =

     4
   -12
   -11
    -1
    13
     7
```